# What do device type numbers mean?

Tags: devices, block-device, character-special-files

`file /dev/*` prints the description of a bunch of files as "block special (M/N)" and "character special (M/N)", where M and N are numbers. For example:

```
$ file /dev/null
/dev/null: character special (1/3)
```

`man file` doesn't seem to document these, but refers vaguely to `man stat`, which seems to refer to these as major and minor device types. `apropos 'device type'` finds nothing. So what do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 7):

Devices on Unix have a type (e.g. character or block), a major number (which typically refers to a driver), and a minor number (which typically refers to an instance).

So, for example:

```
% ls -l /dev/vda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 0 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vda
```

This is a block device, major 253, minor 0.

If we look at `/proc/devices` we see it ends with something similar to

```
Block devices:
  2 fd
259 blkext
  9 md
253 virtblk
254 mdp
```

So we can see that 253 is "virtblk".  Which makes sense, since this is a virtual machine with virtual disks!

The minor number, for this driver, refers to the block device and partition in the device

```
% ls -l /dev/vd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  0 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  1 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  2 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  3 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 16 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 32 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 33 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/vdc1
```

There are some special drivers which don't refer to "real" hardware.  eg

```
% ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Feb  3 09:09 /dev/null
```

This is a character device, major 1, minor 3.  `/proc/devices` tells us driver 1

```
  1 mem
```

We can see this "mem" driver handles a few other devices as well

```
% ls -l /dev | grep ' 1, '
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   7 Feb  3 09:09 full
crw-r--r-- 1 root root      1,  11 Feb  3 09:09 kmsg
crw-r----- 1 root kmem      1,   1 Feb  3 09:09 mem
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   3 Feb  3 09:09 null
crw------- 1 root root      1,  12 Feb  3 09:09 oldmem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem      1,   4 Feb  3 09:09 port
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   8 Feb  3 09:09 random
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   9 Feb  3 09:09 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   5 Feb  3 09:09 zero
```

Comment: That gives me a nice short name and index. Do you know what those short names mean? Some of them are pretty obvious, but I have no idea what "ttyS", "vcs", "sg", and many of the others mean in this context.

Comment: The names are picked by the drivers.  Many of them have manpages; eg `man vcs`.  Others don't.  `ttyS` is serial; `vcs` is `virtual console memory`; `sg` is raw scsi (I think).

Answer (score 3):

Each device node’s type (block or character) and numbers (known as the major and minor number) serve as identifiers for the kernel.

On Linux, the canonical list of devices, with a brief explanation of their function, is maintained [in the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html). You can see there that a major number typically identifies a driver (*e.g.* the TTY device driver) and a minor number identifies a device managed by that driver.